# Run screen through crontab

Tags: bash, cron, gnu-screen

I have an issue about how to run screen through crontab, I made a script which check if a previous session is running and if not restart a screen.
cf screenshots below

[crontab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKSgc.png)

[restard_td.sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMCrX.png)

When I run the script manually it's works fine, by cron, i can see  my output "down, i will restart it " in my log file but no screen available and my script doesn't run.

Has someone got an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try checking the cron log, and use the screen full path.

Comment: What do you meen by "screen full path" ?
I checked the cron log, all is good.
Thx

Comment: /usr/bin/screen

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using screen full path and python full path in my script.
like that

```
/usr/bin/screen -dmS team /usr/local/bin/python /home/admin/scripts/rattrapage/team.py
```